# Word 2003, endnotes, eliminate extra space

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working with a Word (2003 version) document and I have two instances in my end notes where there is an extra space between entries. I have tried clicking on the formating icon on the tool bar (the one that looks like a reversed "P"), but I can't get rid of the space either by back-spacing or by delete. I am still in the track changes mode.

Comment: Sometimes the track changes mode will mess up formatting in Word 2003. Try switching to show the Final result (not Final Showing Markup).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the paragraph spacing is too large:

[image: Paragraph spacing]

If this is the case, simply select the offending text, right click and select **Paragraph...** The window you see above will appear. Reduce the **Before** or **After** spacing to the desired amount (probably 0 pt)